# Select statment with where condtion doesn't work in R

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I want to know can I passing a paremeter with sql query doesn't work

See below sample of my code

```
Vector <- c(123,436,765)
for ( i in 1:length(Vector){
Result <- sqldf("select * from DF where studentID =" , Vector[i] )
Print( Result)}
```

Note that my DF has `studentId` with data type: `integer`

Thanks

Comment: why not `"select * from DF where studentID in Vector"` , where `Vector` is of class `data.frame`.

Comment: See [mcve] on how to ask a question. In particular `DF` or a suitably cut down version should be provided.  Note that the SQL statement(s) must be passed in the first argument which is not the case in the code in the question.  `v <- Vector[i]; fn$sqldf("select * from DF where studentID = $v" )`  Please read `?sqldf` and look at the examples with `fn` showing string interpolation on the sqldf github page.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer plain R, but if you want to use sql-like languages on data.frame you should consider using dplyr, that is pretty much mainstream nowdays.
Here a working example of doing an operation like the one you mentioned.
The pipe %>% simply take what is on the the left and put it as first argument on function of the right, making easier nested functions.

```
required(dplyr)
iris
iris <- tbl_df(iris)
iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length<=5) %>% select(Species)
```